# AWS EC2 SSL error: Getting 'ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR' and 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-acm

The EC2 instance is working fine and accessible with http and via the public IP address.

I am using LoadBalancer with Amazon issued public certificate. LoadBalancer is listening to HTTP at 80 and HTTPS at 443.

[Security Groups inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhuFE.png)

I am running nodejs app on the EC2.

When the app is listening to port 80 https://domain is showing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when tried to access it via browser

When the app is listening to port 443 https://domain is showing ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Route 53 is pointing the domain with A address to the public IP of the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route 53 should point to the DNS of the LoadBalancer.

Also, SecurityGroup should point to the EC2 instance with the same port but must with HTTP protocol. As this is an internal communication and no SSL is needed or supported.